# MultiThread Python with insert to Postgree

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql

I have an error when use multithread in the python.

main.py

```
postgreSQL_pool = configPg.conPg()
conn3 = postgreSQL_pool.getconn()
cur3 = conn3.cursor()
conn2 = postgreSQL_pool.getconn()
cur2 = conn2.cursor()
t1arg = res[0:5]
th1 = 'th1'
t2arg = res[5:10]
th2 = 'th2'
t1 = threading.Thread(target=insertAll.insert_All, args=[t1arg,th1,cur3,conn3,])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=insertAll.insert_All, args=[t2arg,th2,cur2,conn2,])
t1.start()
t2.start()   
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

insertAll.py

```
def insert_All(res1,th,cur3,conn3): 
    count = 0       
    for line in res1:
        
        start_time = time.time()
        sourceOra.ArraySource(count,res1)
        insertCustAll, paramCustAll = Customer.insertCustomer()
        insertAccountAll,paramAccountAll = account.insertAccount()
        insertAll = insertCustAll + insertAccountAll
        paramAll = paramCustAll + paramAccountAll 
        cur3.execute(insertAll,paramAll)
        # commit changes
        conn3.commit()
```

configPg.py

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import pool

> def conPg():
>     #global postgreSQL_pool
>     postgreSQL_pool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(5, 20,user = "xxx",
>                                                 password = "yyyy",
>                                                 host = "127.0.0.0",
>                                                 port = "5432",
>                                                 database = "zzzzz")
>     return postgreSQL_pool
>     #if(postgreSQL_pool):
>     #   print("Connection pool created successfully")
> 
>     # Use getconn() to Get Connection from connection pool
>     #ps_connection  = postgreSQL_pool.getconn()
```

The error is always get duplicate result although I already slice the list for each thread.
Can some one help me.. How to use multithread in python with postgree?

Regards

Comment: What is 'sourceOra'?  What is the exact error do you get?

Comment: Hi @jjanes , SourceOra is the source of my program, it will get data from Oracle DB. I Already solve this issue with change into Multiprocessing from multiThread